# Как получить id заказа, чтобы вернуться на страницу после удаления позиции заказа?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Я создаю через форму заказ, указываю название, стоимость, дату, статус. Данные попадают в таблицу tb_orders.
Далее перехожу на страницу заказа и внутри заказа добавляю позиции заказа через форму. Данные попадают в таблицу tb_items и выводятся на странице заказа. Тут все хорошо работает.
Мне нужно добавить функционал удаления позиции заказа. Это тоже реализовал, все удаляется из базы, НО не могу понять как мне сделать переход, после исполнения скрипта удаления позиции.
То есть как получить id заказа в файле скрипта удаления, чтобы осуществить переход в тот же самый заказ из которого удалял позицию? В скрипт удаления я передаю id позиции с помощью GET запроса.

Скрипт удаления:

```
<?php
    require_once '../config/connect.php';

    $item_id = $_GET['id'];

    $item_delete = "DELETE FROM tb_items WHERE `id` = '$item_id'";
    $item_delete = mysqli_query($connect, $item_delete);

    header('Location: ../order.php');
?>
```

Кусок кода, где получаю id позиции заказа:

```
<tbody>
<?php
           foreach ($item_view as $item){
     ?>
            <tr>
                   <td> <?= $item[2] ?> </td>
                   <td> <?= $item[3] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?= $item[4] ?> </td>
                    <td> <?= $item[5] ?> </td>
                    <td><a href="vendor/delete_item.php?id=<?= $item[0] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
                    </tr>
     <?php
           }
      ?>
</tbody>
```

П.с. при добавлении позиции к заказу все ок, получаю id заказа через скрытый input в форме через POST

```
<form action="vendor/create_item.php" method="POST">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?= $order_view['id'] ?>">
    <input name="item_name" type="text">
    <input name="item_cost" type="text">
    <input name="item_quantity" type="text">
    <textarea name="item_tz"></textarea>
    <p><button type="submit">Добавить</button></p>
</form>
```

Добавляю через следующий скрипт:

```
<?php 
    require_once '../config/connect.php';

    $order_id = $_POST['id'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_cost = $_POST['item_cost'];
    $item_quantity = $_POST['item_quantity'];
    $item_tz = $_POST['item_tz'];

    $item_create = "INSERT INTO tb_items (order_id, item_name, item_cost, item_quantity, item_tz) VALUES ('$order_id', 
    '$item_name', '$item_cost', '$item_quantity', '$item_tz')";
    $item_create = mysqli_query($connect, $item_create);

    header('Location: ../order.php?id=' . $order_id);
?>
```

Comment: Как минимум можно получить ИД заказа (он же order_id) перед удалением из той же таблицы tb_items.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.**
Перед удалением позиции получите из базы данных id заказа на основе id позиции. Не знаю, какая у вас структура БД, но уверен, что это возможно.

**Вариант 2.** (экономичнее, так как нет лишнего запроса к БД)

В том месте, где у вас выводится ссылка на удаление позиции

```
<td><a href="vendor/delete_item.php?id=<?= $item[0] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
```

Добавьте в ссылку параметр с id заказа. Есть подозрение, что в том скрипте id заказа должен быть недалеко. Будет как-то так:

```
<td><a href="vendor/delete_item.php?order=<?= $order_id ?>&id=<?= $item[0] ?>">Удалить</a></td>
```

P.S. в качестве занудства, порекомендую отказаться от процедурного стиля при работе с БД и [перейти на ООП](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php). Времени потратите немного, зато ваш код сразу получит +100 к крутости

Comment: Лучше бы порекомендовал перейти на подготовленые выражения. А то сейчас кто угодно может чужие корзины чистить и не только.

Comment: Сергей Маяк, спасибо за подробное разъяснение и касательно ООП. Сегодня попробую разобраться с этим. Я занимаюсь этим как хобби, пишу небольшую программку для ведения производства в типографии :)